# Why can't Box<dyn T> be used as an associated type which needs to implement T?

Tags: rust, traits

I'd like to use `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` as an associated type which needs to implement `std::error::Error`:

```rust
trait Foo {
    type Error: std::error::Error;
}

struct Bar();

impl Foo for Bar {
    type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dc208998bfd952bc408f3cb996e188b2)

However, this does not seem to work:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:8:18
  |
1 | trait Foo {
  |       --- required by a bound in this
2 |     type Error: std::error::Error;
  |                 ----------------- required by this bound in `Foo`
...
8 |     type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::error::Error` for `std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>`
```

As far as I understood the documentation, `Box<T>` implements `std::error::Error` if `T` does it. I also tried to create a custom trait `SizedError: std::error::Error + Sized` and use a `Box<dyn SizedError>` but that doesn't help either.

Is there any way I can set `Foo::Error` such that I can return any error?

Comment: no you can't, best you can do I think is https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=72222c2fdea547a126d746c5e4299413

Comment: Since `Box<dyn Error>` does not implement `Error`, you will have to either remove the constraint or define your own error type instead of `Box<dyn Error>`.

Comment: @E_net4hasmanyfriends Thank you for the link to the related question. I will resort to a custom error type. It seems that allowing unsized types would conflict with other implementations: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/68186